# Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

Is it possible to modify an active call by overlaying a sound track during the call? I looked up the SDK, but couldn't find any API to do this in the documentation.

I am trying to investigate the feasibility of playing a previously recorded call/audio clip onto an ongoing call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify an active call by overlaying a sound track during the call?

No, sorry, there is no API to access the in-call audio stream.

Comment: Is call recording possible then? How would it work without access to the in-call audio stream?

Comment: @Shoan: "Is call recording possible then?" -- not that I am aware of. There are some tricks people play by having the device in speakerphone mode, but that's about it.

Comment: Where did you get this information? Is this documented somewhere? I have a client asking for this and I'd like to tell them it's not possible but I'm not sure this stack-o answer will cut it.

Comment: @Typeoneerror: 2009 Google I|O Conference, Android "Fireside Chat" session. The in-call audio apparently does not even make it into the operating system.

Comment: In our case, we modified the framework layer to make it work.

Comment: @CommonsWare  There is no direct API for that..agreed, i am just curious of how the fake sounds application work.. I am trying to play an audio through the speaker, microphone catching it is enough for me