# how can I play a sound using a phone call in android?

Tags: android

I am making calls using my app , but now i need to something very funny with call means i need to play recording sounds so that other person on call can hear it .
Is it possible in android ?
Please help

Comment: it was very nice to type the answer rather then typing above line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900564/play-an-audio-clip-onto-an-ongoing-call)