# Sending Streaming Audio on a Phone call

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

I have seen that it seems to be imposible to send an audio (mp3, ogg,...) to a phone call, but i wanted to know if it's possible to play an mp3 in the phone so it's reproduced in max volume when call established.

Comment: If you mean playing it in the loudspeaker at high volume so that it gets picked up by the microphone, then yes, you can do this by enabling speaker phone mode. But this will sound awful both to you and the person at the far end, and you'll end up routing the call audio to the loudspeaker as well (i.e. not just the music).

Comment: Thx man, i was thinking on building an app that just only hitting a button then raises an automatic call to emergencies with a predefined voice message. I was thinking on people with just a few seconds until gets unconcious. But it seems not to be possible :(

Comment: Hi Did you solve that? I mean disable the echo cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. There's no API or hardware support for that. Someone else asked a similar question: [Call Audio Stream Modification in Android 4.0 ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544992/call-audio-stream-modification-in-android-4-0-ics)