# Inject audio into voice stream in android

Tags: android, mobile

I have an idea to build an android application for dumb people which can be helped to answer phone calls. I thought to convert the text into voice and then transfer through call stream.Is it still not possible to play audio so that other party can hear during a phone call in android platforms

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, the short answer still seems to be no.

I would love to be shown wrong on this.
It seems however that the issue goes back to the hardware level and even when that's exposed, Android isn't coded to take advantage of it.

There's a good [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544992/call-audio-stream-modification-in-android-4-0-ics).

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

All Xperia phones have a built-in Answering Machine. When a call comes..the phone can pickup automatically and answer with a pre-recorded voice message which you can customize any time.may you try with these phones.