# Android: How to respond to Incoming caller with prerecorded voice clip ".mp3"?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in which i have successfully detects the incoming call programatically but now i want to give the prerecorded message to caller saying e.g. "I'm busy I'll call you later, bye". and disconnect the call.

How to implement above functionality in ANDROID ?

Thank you and Have nice day.

Comment: You can't play audio into a call on Android. This has been asked many many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play an audio file on a voice call in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784221/how-to-play-an-audio-file-on-a-voice-call-in-android)

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900564/play-an-audio-clip-onto-an-ongoing-call) and approximately a thousand other questions

Answer (score 0):

This is an advanced feature & not implemented till now. It is not possible to just play a sound to the caller. Android has no access to the in-call audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

No, the best that you would be able to accomplish is playing a sound through the speaker so the microphone can pick it up. There are no api's that can accomplish that.